# How do you specify a serverless database in an ARM template in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, serverless, azure-sql-managed-instance

How does one specify a General Purpose: Serverless tier for Azure SQL Database (Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances resource) in an Azure Resource Manager (ARM) template?

What is the appropriate value for {“resources”: [{...,  “sku”: {..., “tier”: ???}}]}

In short, how can I provisión a serverless DB using infrastructure-as-code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a template (template.json):

```
{
    "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2014-04-01-preview/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "collation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "databaseName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "tier": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "skuName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "maxSizeBytes": {
            "type": "int"
        },
        "serverName": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "serverLocation": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "sampleName": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "zoneRedundant": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": false
        },
        "licenseType": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "readScaleOut": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": "Disabled"
        },
        "numberOfReplicas": {
            "type": "int",
            "defaultValue": 0
        },
        "minCapacity": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "autoPauseDelay": {
            "type": "string",
            "defaultValue": ""
        },
        "databaseTags": {
            "type": "object",
            "defaultValue": {}
        },
        "enableADS": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": false
        },
        "enableVA": {
            "type": "bool",
            "defaultValue": false
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "condition": "[parameters('enableVA')]",
            "apiVersion": "2016-01-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "name": "[variables('storageName')]",
            "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "kind": "Storage",
            "properties": {}
        },
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases",
            "apiVersion": "2017-10-01-preview",
            "location": "[parameters('serverLocation')]",
            "tags": "[parameters('databaseTags')]",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/', parameters('databaseName'))]",
            "properties": {
                "collation": "[parameters('collation')]",
                "maxSizeBytes": "[parameters('maxSizeBytes')]",
                "sampleName": "[parameters('sampleName')]",
                "zoneRedundant": "[parameters('zoneRedundant')]",
                "licenseType": "[parameters('licenseType')]",
                "readScale": "[parameters('readScaleOut')]",
                "readReplicaCount": "[parameters('numberOfReplicas')]",
                "minCapacity": "[parameters('minCapacity')]",
                "autoPauseDelay": "[parameters('autoPauseDelay')]"
            },
            "sku": {
                "name": "[parameters('skuName')]",
                "tier": "[parameters('tier')]"
            }
        },
        {
            "condition": "[parameters('enableADS')]",
            "apiVersion": "2017-03-01-preview",
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/securityAlertPolicies",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/Default')]",
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/', parameters('databaseName'))]"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "state": "Enabled",
                "disabledAlerts": [],
                "emailAddresses": [],
                "emailAccountAdmins": true
            }
        },
        {
            "condition": "[parameters('enableVA')]",
            "apiVersion": "2018-06-01-preview",
            "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers/vulnerabilityAssessments",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('serverName'), '/Default')]",
            "properties": {
                "storageContainerPath": "[if(parameters('enableVA'), concat(reference(variables('storageName'), '2018-02-01').primaryEndpoints.blob, 'vulnerability-assessment'), '')]",
                "storageAccountAccessKey": "[if(parameters('enableVA'), listKeys(variables('storageName'), '2018-02-01').keys[0].value, '')]",
                "recurringScans": {
                    "isEnabled": true,
                    "emailSubscriptionAdmins": true,
                    "emails": []
                }
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/databases/', parameters('databaseName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/', variables('storageName'))]",
                "[concat('Microsoft.Sql/servers/', parameters('serverName'), '/securityAlertPolicies/Default')]"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "subscriptionId": "[subscription().subscriptionId]",
        "resourceGroupName": "[resourceGroup().name]",
        "uniqueStorage": "[uniqueString(variables('subscriptionId'), variables('resourceGroupName'), parameters('serverLocation'))]",
        "storageName": "[tolower(concat('sqlva', variables('uniqueStorage')))]"
    }
}
```

And here is the parameters file of the template (parameters.json):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "collation": {
            "value": "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
        },
        "databaseName": {
            "value": "MorilloServerless"
        },
        "tier": {
            "value": "GeneralPurpose"
        },
        "skuName": {
            "value": "GP_S_Gen5_1"
        },
        "maxSizeBytes": {
            "value": 34359738368
        },
        "sampleName": {
            "value": ""
        },
        "serverLocation": {
            "value": "eastus2"
        },
        "serverName": {
            "value": "morillo"
        },
        "zoneRedundant": {
            "value": false
        },
        "licenseType": {
            "value": "LicenseIncluded"
        },
        "readScaleOut": {
            "value": "Disabled"
        },
        "numberOfReplicas": {
            "value": 0
        },
        "minCapacity": {
            "value": "0.5"
        },
        "autoPauseDelay": {
            "value": "60"
        },
        "databaseTags": {
            "value": {}
        },
        "enableADS": {
            "value": false
        },
        "enableVA": {
            "value": false
        }
    }
}
```

Look at the SKUName to know how to specify a Serverless database.

Comment: Thank you. Indirectly, you pointed at the underlying issue. I was trying to use a `Microsoft.Sql/managedInstances` template type, when I should have been using a `Microsoft.Sql/servers/databases` type. Serverless is only an option for Azure SQL Single Database.

Comment: Thank you for sharing with us this experience. It may help others in the future,

Comment: I assume that "minCapacity" is the minimum number of vCPUs. Is there no param for the maximum number of vCPUs?

Comment: @Leonardo that is the minimum performance per database when using elastic pool. You can use maxCapacity to specify the maximum performance per database when using elastic pool